# No camera view on ZXing custom overlay with Xamarin.IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, zxing

Im using Zxing on my Xamarin.IOS App, i built a custom overlay it shows correctly but with no camera view at all "when i move the phone randomly on front of QR Code it scans it", but there is no camera view on the new custom overlay so the user can see what his camera have.

This is the custom overlay class

```
public class CustomOverlayView : ZXing.Mobile.ZXingScannerView
{
    public UIButton ButtonTorch;
    public UIButton ButtonCancel;
    nfloat TopMargin = 200;
    nfloat SideMargins = 50;
    public CustomOverlayView()
    {
        ButtonCancel = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        ButtonCancel.Frame = new CGRect(0, this.Frame.Height - 60, this.Frame.Width / 2 - 100, 100);
        ButtonCancel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;
        ButtonCancel.SetTitle("Cancel", UIControlState.Normal);
        this.AddSubview(ButtonCancel);


    }
    public void HandleScan(ZXing.Result _res)
    {
        //return _res;
    }
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        this.StartScanning(HandleScan);
        TopMargin = this.Frame.Height / 3;
        SideMargins = this.Frame.Width / 6;
        using (CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {

            //set up drawing attributes
            g.SetLineWidth(0);
            UIColor.DarkGray.SetFill();
            UIColor.Black.SetStroke();

            //Create top Rect
            var path = new CGPath();

            path.AddLines(new CGPoint[]{
                new CGPoint (0, 0),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, 0),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (0, TopMargin)});

            path.CloseSubpath();

            g.AddPath(path);
            g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);

            //Create bottom Rect
            path = new CGPath();

            path.AddLines(new CGPoint[]{
                new CGPoint (0, this.Frame.Height),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, this.Frame.Height),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (0, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin)});

            path.CloseSubpath();

            g.AddPath(path);
            g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);


            //Create left rect
            path = new CGPath();

            path.AddLines(new CGPoint[]{
                new CGPoint (0, TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (SideMargins, TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (SideMargins, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (0, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin)});

            path.CloseSubpath();

            //add geometry to graphics context and draw it
            g.AddPath(path);
            g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);

            //Create right rect
            path = new CGPath();

            path.AddLines(new CGPoint[]{
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width-SideMargins, TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin),
                new CGPoint (this.Frame.Width-SideMargins, this.Frame.Height-TopMargin)});

            path.CloseSubpath();

            //add geometry to graphics context and draw it
            g.AddPath(path);
            g.DrawPath(CGPathDrawingMode.FillStroke);
        }

    }
    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        ButtonCancel.Frame = new CGRect(this.Frame.Width/2-75, this.Frame.Height - TopMargin +40, 150, 40);
        ButtonCancel.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
        ButtonCancel.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
        ButtonCancel.Layer.BorderColor = new CGColor(255, 255, 255);
    }

}
```

And here im calling the scanner to start

```
scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner();
        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = true;
        scanner.CustomOverlay = customOverlay;
        customOverlay.ButtonCancel.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
        {
            scanner.Cancel();
        };
        //scanner.ScanContinuously(StartScanner_);
        result = await scanner.Scan();
```

Comment: Perhaps if you showed us your code we could tell you what you're doing wrong?

Comment: @Jason I added the code , hope you can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to run your application on iOS system, I suggest you use the AVFoundation framework to implement the QRCode scanner.

Because:

1. It's for sure that AVFoundation have a more batter performance than ZXing on iOS;
2. If you want to customize the UI, using AVFoundation is more convenient;
3. AVFoundation is provided by Apple, I don't think any Third-Party framework can be more stable than Apple's one.

There is a sample for how to use AVFoundation implement it on my GitHub, you can also use it as a library.

Link : [QRCode scanner sample for Xamarin.iOS](https://github.com/lwnwowone/QRCodeSample)

Hope it can help you.

If there are some reason make you have to use the ZXing framework, could you tell me some details? I'm willing to help you.

Comment: Im thinking about using AV for IOS  and Zxing for android , if this gives us a better performance however , when i run the take the PreviewView Class and the and copies the viwController to my view controller on  my App , when i try to run it gives me a null reference exception on the method ViewWillApear line "SessionQueue.Dispatch" , any toughts ?

Comment: Could you just post some your code somewhere? I can't get your point. I don't use ViewWillApear at all in my sample.